# How to make all textbox empty if selectbox is empty

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone help me how to make all my textbox with class(`number`) empty if the specific selectbox id (`uniq_id`) is empty....anyone know how to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#uniq_id').on('select', function () {
    $(this).attr('oldVal', $(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
    $('.number').val('');
});

 $('#uniq_id').on('click', function(){
    $('.number').val('');
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#uniq_id").change(function(){
  if($("#uniq_id").val()=="")
  {
    $(".number").val("");
  }
});
```

**Update**

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aAJfG/)